# Google Cloud Storage - how to receive specific generation of file in Node.JS

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am using @google-cloud/storage for accessing the GCS API. After enabling versioning, I am trying to fetch a specific generation of a file using the following code:

```
bucket.file(`${name}#${generationId}`).download({
    destination
}).then(() => {
    res.set({
        'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg'
    });
    return res.status(200).sendFile(destination);
})
```

Where `name` is the complete object name and `generationId` contains the number of the generation of the file.

However, if I am executing above code within Google Cloud Functions, I am receiving the following error message:

`ApiError: No such object: my-bucket/image-mxmg569kdvnby6z85mi#1522107649220516`

I am sure that the file and generation exists, as I have checked it with the JSON API explorer. My guess is that `@google-cloud/storage` does not support file versioning (yet), the documentation did not contain any information. Does anyone have experience with that?

Comment: I couldn’t reproduce your issue, but found this example [https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples/blob/master/functions/imagemagick/index.js] where an image is downloaded from the bucket and it worked for me. Also here [https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-versioning] and here [https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/using-object-versioning#access-object-json] you have some more information about object versioning for Google Cloud Storage objects.

Answer (score 1):

If you set `options.generation` when instantiating the File object, it should work! https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-storage/blob/4f4f1b4043c4f70ee99f051499ac62e893abdde0/src/file.js#L82

```
bucket.file(name, { generation: generationId })
```